# Save a div content in a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, store

First of all, in my site DIV's are dynamically added, with a unique ID (like div0, div1, div2...). Those DIV's can be added or deleted by the user: when added, an array store the DIV unique ID; when deleted, the same array delete the DIV id. 
All those DIV's have a lot of input fields, and I want to store this content (even if it's blank). I've searched for a solution and I found something like that:

```
var numCookies=0;
function setCookie(){
    var name;
    for(var i=0; i<arrayDivs.length; i++){//ArrayDivs is the array with the DIV id's.
          name='cookie'+numCookies;
          $.cookie(name, $('#'+arrayDivs[i]).html(),{expires:10});                 
          numCookies++;                                                         
    }
}
```

When I try to "show" (alert) - for example - 'cookie0', the alert is "null".

```
name='cookie0';
alert(name);
var myCookie=($.cookie(name));
alert(myCookie); //here the alert is 'null'
```

At least 1 div is created, so the "arrayDivs" isn't empty, and the "cookie0" is created.
Obviously I'm doing something wrong (very wrong haha). How can I store a DIV (and all it's content) in a cookie? If this implementation isn't completely wrong, how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you create a demo using [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: can you explain the need to store the div and not just some values

Comment: you better use `localStorage`

Comment: Just a note. You don't want to be storing entire DIV contents in cookies. Cookies have limits on how much data it can store and with large amount of markups, you will hit it and then you will see truncated data, which is bad.

My suggestion, use a library like amplifyjs and use local storage to store your div data. it is very simple to use.

-Suj

Comment: 4 K is a LOT of markup, but otherwise I agree

Comment: @mplungjan I have different types of DIV. One DIV gather information about television interviews, other div gather information about stand up comedy, and so on. All the information inside the DIV will be used in a database.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I will as soon as I arrive home.

Comment: @SujeshArukil I will take a look on this library

Comment: @imkost Thanks! I will search for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can get cookies by iteration

```
var nameEQ = 'cookie0' ;
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) 
             result=c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);//this will be the cookie0 :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May you can try this simple example first to get started:

```
// set
$.cookie("cookie", $('#dvContainer').html())

// get
var content = $.cookie("cookie");
var $dvContainer = $('<div class="">' + content + '</div>');

$('body').append($dvContainer);
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8UpM8/)

Answer (score 0):

### Try out this

http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/zSBnG/

**Use a common class for the div's and use the following code block.**

JS Code:-

```
var numCookies = 0;

$(function () {
    $(".cookieClass").each(function () {
        name = 'cookie' + numCookies;
        $.cookie(name, $(this).html(), {
            expires: 10
        });
        numCookies++;
    });

    $("#btnCookie").on("click",function(){
        alert("Cookie 0 : " +$.cookie("cookie0"));
        alert("Cookie 1 : " +$.cookie("cookie1"));
        alert("Cookie 2 : " +$.cookie("cookie2"));
    });

});
```

HTML Code:-

```
<div id="div0" class="cookieClass">val1</div>
<div id="div1" class="cookieClass">val2</div>
<div id="div2" class="cookieClass">val3</div>


<input type="button" id="btnCookie" value="Show Cookie"></input>
```